# I tried the java language using netbeans 12 with jdk version 8, but it always got an error in the output

Tags: java

```
package datakaryawan;

import java.io.Console;

public class InputConsole {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String nama;
        int usia;

        // membuat objek console
        Console con = System.console();

        // mengisi variabel nama dan usia dengan console
        System.out.print("Inputkan nama: ");
        nama = con.readLine();
        System.out.print("Inputkan usia: ");
        usia = Integer.parseInt(con.readLine());

        // mengampilkan isi variabel nama dan usia
        System.out.println("Nama kamu adalah: " + nama);
        System.out.println("Saat ini berusia " + usia + " tahun");
    }
}
```

Output :

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\Fira\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DataKaryawan -Djavac.includes=datakaryawan/InputConsole.java -Dnb.internal.action.name=run.single -Drun.class=datakaryawan.InputConsole run-single
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\Fira\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DataKaryawan\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Fira\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DataKaryawan\build\built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Fira\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DataKaryawan\build\classes
compile-single:
run-single:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
Inputkan nama:  at datakaryawan.InputConsole.main(InputConsole.java:16)
C:\Users\Fira\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DataKaryawan\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1341: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Fira\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DataKaryawan\nbproject\build-impl.xml:968: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: `System.console()` may return null. Is that the problem?

Comment: the problem is eror at line : "nama = con.readLine();" 
but I checked it and found nothing wrong?